# DataReceivedHandler never fires?

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm working on a project that will read data from a COM port, save it into a datatable, show it in a graph and allow saving/loading data via csv. So far the serial communication and file operations are implemented.

Currently I'm testing it with an arduino, which sends `<uint16>` (including '<>' symbols and the uint16 is any number).

Unfortunately the DataRecievedHandler never seems to be called, which I have tested by getting it to print to a text box in the GUI when data is received. The Arduino's TX light flashes normally as it sends the data, and works with the arduino serial monitor. The COM port seems to connect properly, as it makes the serial line busy so that the arduino software can't connect to it at the same time.

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong? I feel it must be something stupid. I've attached the full code just in case.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace FieldProbe
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        SerialPort _port = new SerialPort();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable(); //set up datatable to hold output
        int numSamples = 0;

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();  //get list of ports connected to PC
            cmbSerialPorts.DataSource = ports;      //use list of ports as combobox options
            _port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);  //create pointer to datareceived event handler

            dt.Clear(); //Clear datatable on start
            dt.Columns.Add("index", typeof(int));           //index
            dt.Columns.Add("dutyCycle", typeof(float));     //0.5 means equal on/off, 1.0 means permanently on
            dt.Columns.Add("frequency", typeof(float));     //probe can go from 40MHz to 10GHz
            dt.Columns.Add("distance", typeof(float));      //antenna to radiator distance in metres (usually 1m)
            dt.Columns.Add("pulseWidth", typeof(float));    //calculated from duty cycle and frequency
            dt.Columns.Add("level", typeof(int));           //output in V/m

            chChart.Series["series1"].XValueMember = "level";
            chChart.Series["series1"].YValueMembers = "index";
            chChart.DataSource = dt;
            chChart.DataBind();
        }

        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (btnConnect.Text == "Connect")   //if user clicks connect button
            {

                if (cmbSerialPorts.SelectedIndex > -1)  //if port valid
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("You selected port '{0}'", cmbSerialPorts.SelectedItem));
                    Connect(cmbSerialPorts.SelectedItem.ToString());    //go to connect function
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please select a port first");
                }
            }
            else    //if user clicks disconnect button
            {
                btnConnect.Text = "Connect";
                _port.Close();
            }

        }

        private void Connect(string portName)
        {
            _port = new SerialPort(portName);   //set up serial port using static values (make editable in a config file?)
            if (!_port.IsOpen)
            {
                _port.BaudRate = 9600;  //CHANGE ME AFTER ARDUINO TESTING!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                _port.DataBits = 8;
                _port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                _port.Parity = Parity.None;
                _port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
                _port.RtsEnable = true; //CHANGE ME AFTER ARDUINO TESTING!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                _port.DtrEnable = true; //CHANGE ME AFTER ARDUINO TESTING!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                try
                {
                    _port.Open();   //connect to port
                    btnConnect.Text = "Disconnect";
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("ERROR: Port invalid or in use!");
                    btnConnect.Text = "Connect";
                }
            }
        }

        private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string indata = sp.ReadExisting();  //read data from port
            string indataString = Regex.Match(indata, @"\d+").Value;    //extract number (still a string)
            int indataInt = Int32.Parse(indataString);      //convert string to int

            teIncomingData.AppendText(indata);  //append number to text box for testing
            teIncomingData.AppendText("test1"); //show text in textbox if this function is called

            numSamples++;

            var pulseWidth = nudDutyCycle.Value / (nudFrequency.Value * 100);

            object[] o = {numSamples, nudDutyCycle.Value, nudFrequency.Value, nudDistance.Value, pulseWidth, indataInt};
            dt.Rows.Add(o);
            chChart.DataBind();
        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "csv files (*.csv)|*.csv*";
            saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
            saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "csv";
            saveFileDialog1.AddExtension= true;

            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, dtToCSV());
            }
        }

        private string dtToCSV()
        {
            string file = "";

            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                file = string.Concat(file, col.ColumnName, ",");

            file = file.Remove(file.LastIndexOf(','), 1);
            file = string.Concat(file, "\r\n");

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                foreach (object item in row.ItemArray)
                    file = string.Concat(file, item.ToString(), ",");

                file = file.Remove(file.LastIndexOf(','), 1);
                file = string.Concat(file, "\r\n");
            }

            return file;
        }

        public void saveFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {   //do not delete me, this needs to exist for some reason for saving to work
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are constructing a new serial port class after you are registering the event with a "+=".  So the event is no longer registered.

Comment: Thanks, fixing that worked great. As a note to anybody else who wants to use this code as reference, it still has a lot of bugs that have only exposed themselves after this bit got fixed - I'm very new to c# and OOP in general so it's probably best to take it from tutorials not here, haha!

Comment: Take a gander at this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658109.aspx